# Limit when both numerator and denominator tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a very simple limit question.

$$\lim_{a\to\infty, b\to \infty} \frac{a}{a+b}$$

is the answer can't be determined?

I'd divided the numerator and denominator by $a$, and the denominator is $1 + {b \over a}$. So it depends on ${b \over a}$ and inf/inf is indeterminate?

Comment: You are right .

Comment: In general $\lim_{a\to a_0}\lim_{b\to b_0}f(a,b)\neq \lim_{b\to b_0}\lim_{a\to a_0} f(a,b)$ hence you have to be careful in using the notation $\lim_{a\to +\infty,b\to +\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer cannot be determined. Suppose b = r*a for some real number r. Then the limit is 1/r+1.